# How to use AudioFileStreamSeek with stream file？

Tags: ios, audio-streaming

I use AudioFileStream to play AAC music online. When user try to seek, I need to call AudioFileStreamSeek to know the offset of the stream file I need to seek to, because AAC is VBR music format, I cann't know the offset without AudioFileStreamSeek.

"After you call this function, the parser assumes the next data passed to the AudioFileStreamParseBytes function starts from the byte offset returned in the outAbsoluteByteOffset parameter." says the documents.

What do I do if I find I do not have the data yet I need to seek to after I called AudioFileStreamSeek? The only thing I can do is to continue parse bytes without seek. In sometime music stop sound and I think it is because I break the promise to give to target data in the right offset of the file.

Ok Question is: If I want to seek to some time stamp say 2:28, how do I get the target file offset without call AudioFileStreamSeek?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raw AAC without a container is not seekable.

The best thing you can do is needle-drop.  If you know the time length of the file and you know the time you want to seek to, then divide the file bytes proportionally and you will get close.  (The codec may hiccup a bit for this, but will usually re-sync itself.)

Another common option is to have something server-side create a text file or something that provides the offsets in the file for you.  This is probably more work than it is worth as you could just wrap the AAC in an MP4 container and that will solve the problem.

Comment: Then how can I know the start offset of audio data? If I'm right, ACC file has some property data in the begin.

Comment: @Tonilee, That I am not sure off.